# Dagger2 - Module must be set

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I have Application component with two modules - applicationModule and activityModule.
In my `MvpApp.java` class i create component with modules:

```
public class MvpApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mApplicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .activityModule(new ActivityModule())
                .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this))
                .build();
    }
}
```

My `ApplicationModule` has constructor with `Application` and i send it. But my `Activity module has constructor:

```
    public ActivityModule(AppCompatActivity activity) {
        this.mActivity = activity;
    }
```

And how can i send my `MainActivity` instance into this constructor?
When i try

```
        mApplicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .activityModule(new ActivityModule(new MainActivity()))
                .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this))
                .build();
```

I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not recommended to provide context to the dagger graph via module constructor. You should use the `@BindsInstance` annotation in your dagger component builder.

Also, you can not create a module with the constructor param of activity. You probably want to inject some object into your `MainActivity`. In this case, you need to create a method in your dagger component with a similar declaration and call it in your activity before calling

`ApplicationComponent`

```
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    // your previous code

    void inject(MainActivity target);
}
```

`MainActivity`

```
@Inject SomeClass someClass; // <- some class you want to inject from graph

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ((MvpApp) getApplicationContext()).mApplicationComponent.inject(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // your code
}
```